# Can’t use any SSH port other than 22 on Amazon EC2

Tags: networking, server, ssh, firewall, amazon-ec2

I recently setup a Ubuntu server on Amazon EC2, and I'm accessing it from my windows computer through ssh via putty. After installing LAMP, I try to change the SSH port 22 to another number but after changing the port and allowing it on firewall I cannot connect to that specified port. It always says *"connection timeout"*.

Seems OK when checked using `netstat -tnlp | grep ssh`.
I get this:

```
tcp    0    0 0.0.0.0:2222       0.0.0.0:*      LISTEN      8963/sshd
tcp6   0      0 :::2222               :::*      LISTEN      8963/sshd
```

I don't know what is wrong in my configuration. Can someone please help me?

Answer (score 3):

This is an EC2 specific issue. The server is listening on the right ports, but Amazon's default security group doesn't allow ingress on ports other than a few default ones.

You need to log into the ec2 control panel and allow for port 2222 specifically. You do this by either creating a new security group and assigning it to your instance (preferable) or editing the default one.

More info on security groups to be found here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-network-security.html#security-group-rules

Comment: I can't change the default port, the field is not writable and grey.